# Why does JSON.parse throw a cross-origin error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

Without JSON.parse the following code works fine. If I try to parse or stringify my data object, I receive a cross-origin error. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I have the following piece of code in Title.js:

```
const { name, show_title } = JSON.parse(data.attributes);
```

And this is my data object that I am passing along from Title.stories.js:

```
{"attributes":{"name":"testNameAttribute","show_title":"0"}}
```

I am receiving the following error in Chrome:

> Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to
>   the actual error object in development.
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.dabd386ab27fa6eddf93.bundle.js:74131:19)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.dabd386ab27fa6eddf93.bundle.js:74175:31)
>       at beginWork$$1 (http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.dabd386ab27fa6eddf93.bundle.js:99439:7)
>       at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.dabd386ab27fa6eddf93.bundle.js:98347:12)
>       at workLoopSync (http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.dabd386ab27fa6eddf93.bundle.js:98323:22)
>       at performSyncWorkOnRoot (http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.dabd386ab27fa6eddf93.bundle.js:97891:11)
>       at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.dabd386ab27fa6eddf93.bundle.js:97299:7)
>       at scheduleRootUpdate (http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.dabd386ab27fa6eddf93.bundle.js:100654:3)
>       at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.dabd386ab27fa6eddf93.bundle.js:100682:10)
>       at updateContainer (http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.dabd386ab27fa6eddf93.bundle.js:100784:10)

And this error in Firefox:

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
>
> Button@http://localhost:9002/main.96db0eff63ba8f27231c.hot-update.js:38:26
>   renderWithHooks@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:90029:18
>   mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:92444:13
>   beginWork$1@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:93793:16
>   callCallback@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:74071:14
>   invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:74120:16
>   invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:74175:31
>   beginWork$$1@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:99439:7
>   performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:98350:12
>   workLoopSync@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:98323:22
>   performSyncWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:97891:11
>   scheduleUpdateOnFiber@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:97299:7
>   scheduleRootUpdate@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:100654:3
>   updateContainerAtExpirationTime@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:100682:10
>   updateContainer@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:100784:10
>   legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer/<@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:101372:7
>   unbatchedUpdates@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:98084:12
>   legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:101371:5
>   render@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:101465:12
>   render/<@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:11741:26
>   render@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:11740:10
>   _callee$@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:11837:20
>   tryCatch@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:127832:40
>   invoke@http://localhost:9002/vendors~main.f1b2a3fffbb517f9fb67.bundle.js:128058:22
>   defineIteratorMethods/

Comment: This is browser-dependent. In Chrome, the error looks opaque for some odd reason. In Firefox, it's not opaque. Don't have a reference, but I wouldn't be surprised if this is considered a bug that they haven't gotten around to fixing

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/45433997#45433997

Comment: @CertainPerformance Firefox does indeed have a different error. I added it in the question

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `attributes` is an object instead of string

```js
/** Attributes is a string */
const data = {
  "attributes": `{
    "name": "testNameAttribute",
    "show_title": "0"
  }`
};
const { name, show_title } = JSON.parse(data.attributes);
console.log(name) //Output "testNameAttribute"


/** Attributes is an object */
const data = {
  "attributes": {
    "name": "testNameAttribute",
    "show_title": "0"
  }
};
const { name, show_title } = JSON.parse(data.attributes);
console.log(name) //Error
```

[image]