# Using Javascript and HTML inside a ternary statement gives error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

Due to react's nature i have to use the ternary operator to output some code. I am getting a parse error because i have JS code as well as html in the output. How can i insert both the JS and html in this ternary statement?

JS

```
<div>
{
props.starring? "..some code"
: 
    (
    const starrarr = JSON.parse("["+props.starring+"]") //this line is giving me an error
    <div className="altactorimg">
       <h6><img src="#" alt="pictures"/>{starrarr[0]}</h6>
       <h6><img src="#" alt="pictures"/>{starrarr[1]}</h6>
       <h6><img src="#" alt="pictures"/>{starrarr[2]}</h6>
    </div>
    )
}
</div>
```

I attempted many things like wrapping them inside brackets, and adding JSON.parse directly inside each  element but still get errors.

Note: the above code is react jsx

Comment: You have 2 options, doing parsing in all three `h6`'s or put that const before { and make ternary also there.

Comment: i know i tried parsing inside all three h6's but react game me a cross origins error

Comment: i'll try the second option

Comment: I don't believe you can declare a const in that place/manner-- I think that is the source of the error, not the ternary.

Comment: right. but when i declare that const anywhere react gives me a cross origins error

Comment: ternary seems like a bad choice for this, why not make it a method and method returns the markup?

Comment: @epascarello i have no choice this is inside react JSX

Comment: I ran your code removing the variable from inside the components and putting it out and I had no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i figured it out. Apparently using JSON.parse to convert the string to an array results in a react cross origin error. To solve this problem i used the JS split method to create an array out of the string and everything works perfectly, with no cross origins error.

Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 3):

Each branch of a ternary must be a single expression. Therefore you need to either define your variable outside of the ternary expression, as I show below, or refactor the expression (e.g. encapsulating the behavior in a function or component).

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  const starrarr = props.starring && JSON.parse(`[${props.starring}]`)

  return (
    <div>
      {props.starring
        ? "..some code"
        : (
          <div className="altactorimg">
            <h6><img src="#" alt="pictures"/>{starrarr[0]}</h6>
            <h6><img src="#" alt="pictures"/>{starrarr[1]}</h6>
            <h6><img src="#" alt="pictures"/>{starrarr[2]}</h6>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: helpful but react returns a cross origin error. It has to do with JSON.parse. do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Uriel The value of `props.starring` is [probably not what you're expecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266141/why-does-json-parse-throw-a-cross-origin-error). Inspect the value in the React Devtools or console.log it and review.

Comment: I do. Its an array. But i just figured it out thanks

Comment: Note that if you expect `props.starring` to be a string like `one,two,three` you would be better served by using `props.starring.split(",")` to create your array. This is safer and more performant than what you show.

Comment: thats exactly what i discovered a few min ago. thanks anyways

Comment: idk why i was using JSON.parse in the first place lol